# Prove this integral is larger than other without evaluating.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a cartesian equation:
      $y = e^x$ from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$
And a parametric equation :
      $x = t + ln(t)$, $y = t - ln(t)$ from $t = 0$ to $t = e$
If I set up integrals for the arc length of these 2 equations, how would I prove that the arc length of the parametric curve is $\sqrt 2$ times bigger than the cartesian curve without evaluating the integrals?

Comment: Is it $0\le x \le e$ or $0\le t \le e$ for the parametric? Or even $1\le t \le e$?

Comment: @πr8 Fixed, its your second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Reparametrise the first curve as $x=\ln t, y=t$, and compare the expressions $\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}$ for each curve.

Remark: Note that for the second curve, $\frac{x+y}{2}=e^{\frac{x-y}{2}}$, which is a rotation and rescaling of the curve $y=e^x$.

Comment: Got it thanks .